How to get total_video_views_by_country_id from facebook graph api
I tried to get total_video_views_by_country_id from the Facebook Graph API and have some error
I tried to get total_video_views_by_country_id from the Facebook Graph API using the endpoint
GET /v20.0/{video-id}/video_insights HTTP/1.1 

via the Graph API Explorer 510171338137924/video_insights/metric=total_video_views_by_country_id
However, when I attempted this on the Graph API Explorer, the result was
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) The value must be a valid insights metric",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "AA1wczXhtw-h7XE8msmeQgY"
  }
}


metric is a query string parameter, not part of the URL path. 510171338137924/video_insights?metric=total_video_views_by_country_id

Thanks. I tried to change it as you suggested, but I still got the same message.

That appears to be a problem with that particular metric; other ones work. Not sure why. Request 510171338137924/video_insights, and you should see everything that is available.
